# Angular: Show preloader when Router is activated/change

Tags: angular, angular-router, preloader

I want to create a preloader when the `router-outlet` is loading a component.

What I wanted is that the preloader will display first and will cover the `router-outlet` and then after a delay (1s) the preloader will be hidden and will show the `router-outlet`.

The point of preloader is to hide the `router-outlet` while it is loading its content like images the preloader will be shown and after a delay the `images/contents` are loaded.

So far what I did is that using `router-outlet` and its event `activate`

```
<div *ngIf="preLoader" class="loader">
  <h2>LOADER</h2>
</div>
<router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)"></router-outlet>

preLoader: boolean;
  onActivate(event : any) {
    this.preLoader = true;
    console.log(this.preLoader);
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.preLoader = false;
    },1000);
  }
```

My [preloader stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/router-outlet-preloader)

If there any better solution?

Comment: Not sure its a good practice to add condition on your router-outlet.
Move the show/hide logic inside your route content and use the [hidden] property along side the ts code that watches for the content to be fetched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a class that applies "display: hidden" to the router-outlet whilst the preloader value is true, which will hide it within the page.

```
<div [class.hide-me]="!preLoader" class="loader">
  ...content to show whilst loading...
</div>
<router-outlet
  [class.hide-me]="preLoader"
  (activate)="onActivate($event)">
</router-outlet>
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I need to use property binding since I will reuse the preloader so the page will not rerender the preloader.